# I have 2 almost identical queries. Why does one run so much faster?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

The explain statements look almost identical. Yet the 1st query runs in 1.234 seconds and the 2nd runs in 23.282 seconds. These are so simila

```
-- Query 1
-- Duration / Fetch 1.234 sec/ 0.000 sec
select  t.taxpayerId, ifnull(t.name, '') name, ifnull(t.name2, '') name2, t.address, t.address2, t.city, t.state, t.zip,t.inBankruptcy, ifnull(bal.balance,0) amountDue, t.emailAddress, t.blocked, ifnull(t.comments, '') as comments, serial, ifnull(p.address, 0),  t.statusCode
from Taxpayer t             
left join Parcel p on p.taxpayer_id = t.id               
left join PersonalProperty pp on pp.taxpayer_id = t.id            
left join (select t.taxpayerID, sum(b.balance) balance from Bill b join TaxpayerHistory t on t.id = b.taxpayer_id where b.balance <> 0 group by t.taxpayerID ) bal on bal.taxpayerId = t.taxpayerId    
where 1 
and (p.mapNumber like '1205100%' or t.id in ((select th.taxpayer_id from Bill b join TaxpayerHistory th on th.id = b.taxpayer_id join ParcelHistory ph on ph.id = b.parcel_id where ph.mapNumber like '1205100%'))) 
and t.name like '%%' 
group by t.taxpayerId         
order by p.mapNumber;
```

```
-- Query 2
-- Duration / Fetch 23.282 sec/ 0.000 sec
select  t.taxpayerId, ifnull(t.name, '') name, ifnull(t.name2, '') name2, t.address, t.address2, t.city, t.state, t.zip,t.inBankruptcy, ifnull(bal.balance,0) amountDue, t.emailAddress, t.blocked, ifnull(t.comments, '') as comments, serial, ifnull(p.address, 0),  t.statusCode
from Taxpayer t 
left join Parcel p on p.taxpayer_id = t.id 
left join TaxpayerHistory th on t.id = th.taxpayer_id 
left join Bill b on th.id = b.taxpayer_id 
left join ParcelHistory ph on b.parcel_id = ph.id 
left join PersonalProperty pp on pp.taxpayer_id = t.id 
left join (select t.taxpayerID, sum(b.balance) balance from Bill b join TaxpayerHistory t on t.id = b.taxpayer_id where b.balance <> 0 group by t.taxpayerID ) bal on bal.taxpayerId = t.taxpayerId 
where 1 
and (p.mapNumber like '1205100%' or ph.mapNumber like '1205100%') 
and t.name like '%%' 
group by t.taxpayerId 
order by p.mapNumber
```

```
-- Query 1 EXPLAIN
+---+------------+----------+------+---------------------------------------+-----------+--------+-------------------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |select_type |table     |type  |possible_keys                          |key        |key_len | ref                     |rows   | Extra                                                              |
+---+------------+----------+------+---------------------------------------+-----------+--------+-------------------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |PRIMARY     |t         |ALL   |IX_TaxpayerID_Name,IX_TaxpayerID_Only  | null      |null    |null                     |171799 |Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort                        |
|1  |PRIMARY     |p         |ref   |FK8E0FEC                               |FK8E0FEC   |9       |taxpackage.t.id          |1      |Using where                                                         |
|1  |PRIMARY     |pp        |ref   |FKE06C6C                               |FKE06C6C   |9       |taxpackage.t.id          |1      |null                                                                |    
|1  |PRIMARY     |<derived2>|ref   |<auto_key0>                            |<auto_key0>|258     |taxpackage.t.taxpayerId  |10     |null                                                                |
|3  |SUBQUERY    |ph        |range |PRIMARY,map                            |map        |258     |null                     |17     |Using where; Using index                                            |
|3  |SUBQUERY    |b         |ref   |parcel_id,taxpayer_id,XIC_Parcel_Search|parcel_id  |9       |taxpackage.ph.id         |1      |Using where                                                         |
|3  |SUBQUERY    |th        |eq_ref|PRIMARY,taxpayer_id,IX_hist_id_vs_id   |PRIMARY    |8       |taxpackage.b.taxpayer_id |1      |null                                                                |
|2  |DERIVED     |b         |range |taxpayer_id,balance,XIC_Parcel_Search  |balance    |9       |null                     |100204 |Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|2  |DERIVED     |t         |eq_ref|PRIMARY,taxpayerId,account             |PRIMARY    |8       |taxpackage.b.taxpayer_id |1      |null                                                                |
+---+------------+----------+------+---------------------------------------+-----------+--------+-------------------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
-- Query 2 EXPLAIN
+---+------------+----------+------+---------------------------------------+-----------+--------+-------------------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |select_type |table     |type  |possible_keys                          |key        |key_len | ref                     |rows   | Extra                                                              |
+---+------------+----------+------+---------------------------------------+-----------+--------+-------------------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |PRIMARY     |t         |ALL   |IX_TaxpayerID_Name,IX_TaxpayerID_Only  | null      |null    |null                     |171799 |Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort                        |
|1  |PRIMARY     |p         |ref   |FK8E0FEC                               |FK8E0FEC   |9       |taxpackage.t.id          |1      |null                                                                |
|1  |PRIMARY     |th        |ref   |taxpayer_id,IX_hist_id_vs_id           |taxpayer_id|9       |taxpackage.t.id          |7      |Using index                                                         |    
|1  |PRIMARY     |b         |ref   |taxpayer_id,XIC_Parcel_Search          |taxpayer_id|9       |taxpackage.th.id         |1      |null                                                                |
|3  |PRIMARY     |ph        |eq_ref|PRIMARY                                |PRIMARY    |8       |taxpackage.b.parcel_id   |1      |Using where                                                         |
|3  |PRIMARY     |pp        |ref   |FK8E0FEC                               |FK8E0FEC   |9       |taxpackage.t.id          |1      |null                                                                |
|3  |PRIMARY     |<derived2>|ref   |<auto_kev0>                            |<auto_kev0>|258     |taxpackage.t.taxpayerId  |10     |null                                                                |
|2  |DERIVED     |b         |range |taxpayer_id,balance,XIC_Parcel_Search  |balance    |9       |null                     |97322  |Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|2  |DERIVED     |t         |eq_ref|PRIMARY,taxpayerId,account             |PRIMARY    |8       |taxpackage.b.taxpayer_id |1      |null                                                                |
+---+------------+----------+------+---------------------------------------+-----------+--------+-------------------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

It doesn't make any sense. There are practically no differences between the EXPLAIN results. They both search practically the same amount of rows the same way. In query 2 if I swap out

`ph.mapNumber like '1205100%'`

and replace it with

`t.id in ((select th.taxpayer_id from Bill b join TaxpayerHistory th on th.id = b.taxpayer_id join ParcelHistory ph on ph.id = b.parcel_id where ph.mapNumber like '1205100%')))`

from Query 1 then the Duration drops to 1.328 seconds. Even though making that change causes the the rows searched to increase from 97322 to 100204.

Is there some known rule I'm missing, or is there a best practices method that I don't see that's taking place? If anyone can shed light on this I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Some observations:

```
    or t.id in ((select -- IN() and IN(SELECT.. will kill performance

   and t.name like '%%' -- MySQL cannot use an index on LIKE '%...'

 group 
    by t.taxpayerId  

-- in the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate
```

Also, in order to have any chance of analysing a query, always qualify ALL column names, and provide SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for ALL relevant tables.

Comment: And why limit to `t.name like '%%'`?  Isn't that going to just give you every record anyway?